# How can I pass parameters to a @renderpage call for the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that renders 4 other views with @renderpage for create/Update purposes.
My Create page works fine, but now I want to make it possible to Update the Data if needed, but I don't get it to work to pass Data to the rendered pages controllers.
I can't use partial views because I don't have a model at that time.
I get that model within the Edit Call.

I've tried all the approaches I stumbled upon while googling. 
I tried it with a class that holds the parameter I want to pass, I tried simply a test Id and so on. 
The Data won't show up in the controller.

RenderPage call:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "person" }))
        {
            var id = Request["PersonId"];

            if (id != null)
            {
                PageInfo pageinfo = new PageInfo(Int32.Parse(id));
                @RenderPage("~/Views/Person/Edit.cshtml", pageinfo.PostId)
            }

        }
```

Controller:

```
public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        ProjekthafenEntities phentitis = new ProjekthafenEntities();
        // GET: Person
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Person person)
        {
            phentitis.Person.Add(person);
            phentitis.SaveChanges();

            return Json(data: new ResponseData(true, "", "success"));
        }


        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View(phentitis.Person.Find(id));
        }

    }
```

I Expect to get a value in the Edit function, but I only get null.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For all those who are interested, I solved the problem like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Firma", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "firma" }))
        {
            var id = Int32.Parse(Request["FirmaId"]);
            ProjekthafenEntities phentitis = new ProjekthafenEntities();

            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Firma/Edit.cshtml", phentitis.Firma.Find(id));

        }
```

and changed the Controller to this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Firma firma)
        {  
            return View(firma);
        }
```